# XSLT get a variable in case of element name

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I can get an xml with one of three nodes.

```
<root>
  <headerA>
    <!-- Content -->
  </headerA>
</root>
```

in place of `<headerA>` there can be `<headerB>` or `<headerС>` node with similar content. In this case I want to have html output as:

```
<span> Type [X] </span>
```

Where `[X]` is A, B or C depending on the tag name of the element.

Comment: Please be more precise. It's not clear how your sample input and sample output relate.

Comment: sorry, I had some mistakes in formatting. is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tomalak has already observed, your question is rather vague.  It sounds as if you might be asking how to write either a single template for the three kinds of header:

```
<xsl:template match="headerA | headerB | headerC">
  <span>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </span>
</xsl:template>
```

or else how to write similar but distinct templates for them:

```
<xsl:template match="headerA">
    <span> Type A </span>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="headerB">
    <span> Type B </span>
</xsl:template>
<!--* Template for headerC left as an exercise for the reader *-->
```

or else how to write a single template that does slightly different things based on what it matches:

```
<xsl:template match="headerA | headerB | headerC">
  <span>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::headerA">
         <xsl:text> Type A </xsl:type>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="self::headerB">
         <xsl:text> Type B </xsl:type>
      </xsl:when>
      <!--* etc. *-->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:message terminate="yes"
          >I thought this could not happen.</xsl:message>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </span>
</xsl:template>
```

If you figure out which of these helps you, you will be closer to understanding what question you are trying to ask.

Comment: Thank you, the second one is that I looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'header')]">
  <xsl:variable name="type" select="substring-after(name(), 'header')" />
  <span>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' Type ', $type, ' ')" />
  </span>
</xsl:template>
```

This would work for any element named `headerX`, where can be `X` any string.